# C# MVC API URL string value remove case sensitive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have C# MVC API URL localhost/api/APIValues?Name=Nick. All working but only issue is when I typed Name=nick it won't display result. because my database table name field store Nick. Also my Database table name field has some data example Nick, ANN, tristan, Abbott,BUD. How do I remove string(Name) case sensitive MVC API values?
Example, how do I setup both way work localhost/api/APIValues?Name=Nick and localhost/api/APIValues?Name=nick.

This is my C# code.

```js
public IEnumerable<NameDTO> Get(string Name = "")
{
var nameList = (from o in db.People.AsEnumerable()
                       where  o.name == Name                       
                       join s in db.Employee on
                        o.empID equals s.empID
                     
                        select new 
                        {
                            
                           s.empID,
                            o.Id
                        }).ToList();
}
```

My finally out put should work both name "Nick or nick"

```html
localhost/api/APIValues?Name=Nick
localhost/api/APIValues?Name=nick
```

Comment: is ToLower(o.name) == ToLower(Name) an option?

Comment: How about somebody typed ANN, Ann and ann?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Or what is db in this case?

Comment: Yes I am using EF, MVC 5 and MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I think it may help you:

```
    // Use if you want same records  with name you provide

    public List<NameDTO> Get(string Name = "")
    {
        var nameList = (from o in db.People.AsEnumerable()
                        where o.name.Trim().ToLower() == Name.Trim().ToLower()
                        join s in db.Employee on
                         o.empID equals s.empID

                        select new NameDTO()
                        {
                          EmpId =  s.empID,
                           Id = o.Id
                        }).ToList();
    }

    //use this if you want similar records from database

    public IEnumerable<NameDTO> Get(string Name = "")
    {
        var nameList = (from o in db.People.AsEnumerable()
                        where o.name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(Name.Trim().ToLower())
                        join s in db.Employee on
                         o.empID equals s.empID
                       select new NameDTO()
                        {
                          EmpId =  s.empID,
                           Id = o.Id
                        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is remove case sensitive(o.name.Trim().ToLower() == Name.Trim().ToLower()) only issue is some body type localhost/api/APIValues?Name=a   also display all names according to "a" results. How do I string value set type minimum 3 letters

Comment: Remove AsEnumerable() then try  and for setting string value minimum length do validation for textbox

Comment: I am unable to remove AsEnumerable() my API need

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Equals with [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)*:

```
public IEnumerable<NameDTO> Get(string Name = "")
{
var nameList = (from o in db.People.AsEnumerable()
                       where o.name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)      
                       join s in db.Employee on
                        o.empID equals s.empID

                        select new 
                        {

                           s.empID,
                            o.Id
                        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: If I add this line o.name.Equals(Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) it'll say
Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Use: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: sorry I am not clear Use StringComparison, how do I do?

Comment: no any error, but still working only Ann, if I typed ann, it won't work

Comment: Are you using StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Comment: This returns true:
var ann = "ann";
var Ann = "Ann";

var isEqual = ann.Equals(Ann, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: Yes, I did same line copy o.name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: The problem should be on your join then. The string compare will Equal on whatever casing 'Ann' is in. Do you have a row on Employee table for 'Ann'?

Comment: Only Emp table has name "Ann", also Join is no any issue

Comment: how can I use Contains with (o.name.Contains(Name)) StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Answer (score 0):

Made it as simple as it can get. Whenever my query's don't work in a single line it's my preference to break it down into several components. Feel happy to write a one liner though.

```
var nameList= db.People.AsEnumerable();
            People people = new People();
            foreach (var x in nameList)
            {
                var result = x.name.ToLower() == Name.ToLower();
                if (result)
                {
                    people = x;
                }
            }

var Employee =  db.Employee.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmpId == people.EmpId);

NameDTO nameDTO = new NameDTO()
{
 EmpId = Employee.EmpId,
 Id = People.Id
};
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not case sensitive. And as long as yo're using a library that converts your code to SQL (such as EF) this shouldn't be an issue.

```
var nameList = (from o in db.People
                       where  o.name == Name                       
                       join s in db.Employee on
                        o.empID equals s.empID
                        select new 
                        {                            
                           s.empID,
                            o.Id
                        }).ToList();
```

The problem is that you're using AsEnumerable() which actually executes the query and then compares the objects in memory instead of comparing in DB. Watch it in the SQL Profiler and you will see the difference.